# How can I (re)format a partition from a .net application?

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI application which needs to format a partition (single drive letter in Windows XP Embedded).

Is there any other way to do this besides launching the standard windows format program? ..or is that my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by making use of the [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the following control codes seem relevant:

- [IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365155%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - Initializes the specified disk and disk partition table
- [IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365189%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - Partitions a disk according to the specified drive layout and partition information data
- [IOCTL_DISK_VERIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365193%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - Verifies the specified extent on a fixed disk.

For completeness, it's also worth being aware of other options, though probably won't work on XP embedded:

For Vista/Windows Server 2003 (and above), the [IVdsVolumeMF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382948%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) COM interface provides a [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382964%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Also for Windows Server 2003 (and above), the [Win32_Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) WMI Class also has a [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.